# Perl state variable requires explicit package name

Tags: perl

I am having problems getting state variables to work.  I have extensive experience with "my" variables, but getting "state" variables to work hasn't been easy.

Here is a bare minimum example to reproduce the problem:

```
$ perl -e 'use strict; sub test {state $string = ""; print $string; }'
Global symbol "$string" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $string"?) at -e line 1.
Global symbol "$string" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $string"?) at -e line 1.
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

$ perl --version

This is perl 5, version 32, subversion 1 (v5.32.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for the [state](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state) keyword:

> `state` is available only if the "state" `feature` is enabled or if it is
> prefixed with `CORE::`. The "state" feature is enabled automatically
> with a `use v5.10` (or higher) declaration in the current scope.

Here is one way to change your one-liner to avoid the error:

```
$ perl -e 'use strict; use feature "state"; sub test {state $string = ""; print $string; }'
```

The docs mention:

> This feature is available starting with Perl 5.10.

Although you are using Perl version v5.32.1, which is later than 5.10, it is still necessary to explicitly enable the `state` feature using one of the methods shown in the documentation.  This feature is currently not enabled by default for any version of Perl.